# OnChange event is triggered too early using jquery-chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-chosen

I'm using the "Multiple Select" from jquery-chosen (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I have a function which has to be called whenever there's a change with this select (e. g. a new option was chosen or an option was deleted):

```
function getMultiselectVal(){
    var value = $('.chosen-choices').text();
    alert(value);
}
```

My html code from firebug looks like this:

```
<div id="Q2_chosen" class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 350px;" title="">

    <ul class="chosen-choices">
        <li class="search-choice"></li>
        <li class="search-field" onchange="getMultiselectVal();"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop"></div>
</div>
```

This works well when an item was added. I click into the dropdown, select the value I want to add (e. g. "United Kingdom"), the value is added and now my function is called.

But this doesn't work when removing an item. If I click the "x" to remove the item, my function is immediately called (which is bad) and the item stays in the list until my function has finished.

Example:
The list is empty. I now add "United Kingdom". My function alerts "UnitedKingdom". I now add "Germany", my function alerts "UnitedKingdomGermany". I now remove UnitedKingdom, my function alerts "UnitedKingdomGermany" (because the item will only be removed AFTER the function).

So it seems to me:
a) The onChange is called too early.
b) This is synchronous, not asynchronous. If it would be asynchronous, my function wouldn't stop the "removing process".

Comment: I am facing same issue .... tell me please if you have figured out